# cant send a data from client to server

Tags: java, jquery, ajax

guys i am following jquery ajax tutorial .. why this code isnot working

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#div").load( "C:\Users\workspace\AjaxProject\src\Server.java",  name="Memo",function(responseTxt, statusTxt, xhr) {
        if (statusTxt == "success")
           alert("External content loaded successfully!");
        if   (statusTxt == "error")
           alert("Error: " + xhr.status + ": " + xhr.statusText);
      });
   });
</script>
```

the Server.java

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   doGet(request, response);
   System.out.print(""+request.getParameter("name"));
}
```

Comment: We can't call any server program by it's name. We need to call it via configured URL.

Comment: please see the updates it doesnt work

Comment: This is lacking so many details... 1) did you even deploy the java code in a servlet container such as tomcat? 2) you need to load a URL, not "Server.java" 3) "this code is not working" tells us nothing. Whats the error?

Comment: @f1sh 1-yes 2-i did .. i updated the code 3- no errors and not printing anything

Comment: @DinaSaber that's still not a URL. If you deployed it to a local tomcat, the URL should be something like ``http://localhost:8080/AjaxProject/<YourServletMapping>``.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to call any `Servlet` by the name of java program as shown in the example. We need to deploy and run the `Servlet` in it's container and then, we can call it by configured url.

[Here](http://hmkcode.com/java-servlet-send-receive-json-using-jquery-ajax/) is the complete tutorial on how to start an application with `Servlet` and call it using jQuery.